# How can I reduce the animation strength of Animate.css?

Tags: css, animate.css

I am working with some Animate.css animations and I regularly find that the animations are too "strong". I realize this is a subjective thing, but it would be nice if I could tone down the overall strength of the animations. Doing some searches I have not been able to find anything on this, just how to reduce animation delay and duration. Maybe "strength" isn't the correct term, but I am not sure what else you would call it.

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer unless you define what you mean by `strong`

Comment: Sorry, the more I think about this the less I think this will even be possible. But, when I say "strength" I am referring to the overall animations scale. If you look at the "Tada" animation for example, imagine scaling the animation back while retaining the elements original size so that when the animation plays the animation speed is the same, the element size is the same, it's just that the animation itself is lessened. The distances things move are reduced. Hopefully this helps clarify.

Comment: You should dig in the docs for that tool. They say `It's possible to change the duration of your animations, add a delay or change the number of times that it plays:` https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Comment: Thanks Simon. Yes, I understand that I can change the delay and duration, however that is not what I am after. I was trying to figure out if I could scale the animation down instead. It's ok, I don't believe this would even be possible now that I think about it without recreating the animations.